# How to make PHP escape CSV correctly (fgetcsv)?

Tags: php, csv, escaping, fgetcsv

It looks like PHP has issues in fgetcsv or str_getcsv with double quotes and escapes.

here's a simple example from the command line:

```
$ echo '"\"test\""' | php -r '$t=file_get_contents("php://stdin"); print "input: ".$t."\noutput: ".str_getcsv($t)[0];'
```

result:

```
input: "\"test\""
output: \"test\"
```

expected result:

```
input: "\"test\""
output: "test"
```

I would expect the output to be different, because the outer quotes are enclosing quotes, and the inner ones are escaped. The escape character should not be carried to the output.

Why does PHP interpret this different and what is a robust work-around?

Comment: This looks like a PHP bug to me. The docs clearly say "for the default parameter values `""` and `\"` have the same meaning", yet they don't: https://3v4l.org/9FcDI. Can you change the CSV to use the usual (and portable) double double-quote escaping?

Comment: I think so too. We can of course pull the CSV through e.g. a python script to convert the escaping but it is a bit inefficient.

Comment: Also, the bug appears to be bi-directional; fputcsv also doesn't escape the escape character as expected: https://3v4l.org/SZEqr

Comment: The escape character is never escaped in CSV, only the enclosing character (in RFC 4180 anyway). Nevertheless, fputcsv can [produce unparsable output](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=43225) with the default settings.

Answer (score 0):

I used str_replace to get around the problem.

```
str_replace("\\\"", '"', $string);
```

Here's the function I used to fix an entire array of parsed CSV-rows.

```
function fixCSVescapes(&$data) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
        $row = $data[$i];
        $name = $row["name"];
        $fixName = str_replace("\\\"", '"', $name);
        $data[$i]["name"] = $fixName;
    }
}
```

Note that this is a function depending on a specific input. In this case, there's only one column where `\"` could occur, so it only does a replace on that specific column. Hope this is of use for someone.

Comment: This has been reported to PHP many years ago: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55413
Seems like this is something they won't fix, in order to not break backwards compability, and because PHP works fine in removing escapes characters when the escape character is `"` (as it should be according to the RFC). Too bad since, using backslash as an escape character seems to be used by many.